# How to get Data Feed length from Google Merchant Center

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apis-explorer, google-shopping-api

Is that possible to get the number of product in a Google Shopping Data Feed ? Actually, we can get all of the information (name, price, category, …) about each products with this [Google Merchant Center API](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/) code :

```
function productList() {
  var merchantId = 123456; // Replace this with your Merchant Center ID.
  var pageToken;
  var pageNum = 1;
  var maxResults = 10;

  // List all the products for a given merchant.
  do {
    var products = ShoppingContent.Products.list(merchantId, {
    pageToken: pageToken,
    maxResults: maxResults
    });
  Logger.log('Page ' + pageNum);
  if (products.resources) {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.resources.length; i++) {
      Logger.log('Item [' + i + '] ==> ' + products.resources[i]);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No more products in account ' + merchantId);
  }
  pageToken = products.nextPageToken;
  pageNum++;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

But it's take to much time to show all of the products and count them for each clients. Would you have an idea to get the data feed length fastly ? Is there a function ?

Thank you !

Comment: In fact, I was using the wrong Google Merchant Center function… There is Datafeedstatuses that provide the number of items in the feed that is valid. A function that run much faster. :)